# VBA Goalseek loop with multiple variables

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I am trying to create a sub_routine or function to goal seek 4 values for 1000 rows. I haven't been able to find a good example that has both multiple goal seek values and lots of rows.

The below script is the goal seek portion and I started the loop further below. Just not 100% sure on how to properly merge the script.

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$AR$4", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$H$4:$K$4", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"


Sub goal_seek()
    Dim r As Long

    For r = 4 To 1004
    
End Sub
```

TLDR: Trying to find a way to loop through 1000 rows to use Solver to GoalSeek Columns H-K to make Columns M-R equal Columns B-G. I created Column AR which sums the differences which is what I am trying to minimize.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, works in my test environment

```
Sub SolverRevolver()
'This will take a while to run at scale, it took my computer about 30 seconds to run 10 lines as a test
'Solver is funky with VBA. Make sure you have run manually once in your workbook, otherwise solver won't "load".
'You also need to enable solver library in vba. Tools -> References -> Solver (make sure box is checked)

For i = 4 To 1004
    SolverOk SetCell:="$AR$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$H$" & i & ":$K$" & i, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True 'This is for that dialog box at the end
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1 'This is for that dialog box at the end
Next i
End Sub
```

EDIT: If you are interested in more vba solver integrations, check [this](https://peltiertech.com/Excel/SolverVBA.html) out. It's a bit dated, but the code remains valid.